# python handling case in address (lowercase,uppercase)

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm working on a python QGIS plugin that takes address info from specific parcels and lists it. The data is in various cases and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to handle it.

My data looks like this:

```
num addr                city        zip
45  NE   CRESCENT DR    Issaquah    98027
```

The script merges the attributes into a string:

```
45 NE CRESCENT DR, Issaquah, WA 98027
```

I've been using `.title()` which fixes the case in CRESCENT to Crescent, but messes up the NE and DR which should stay caps. Additionally for numerical streets like `234th Ave` I need the "th" to be lowercase.

I would like the output to be:

```
45 NE Crescent DR, Issaquah, WA 98027
```

Any Advice?

Comment: Maybe you could [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) your addr field and apply `.title()` on each element, except predefined elements such as "DR", "RD", "NE", "NW", etc. as well as elements starting with a number.

Comment: Can you show your script?

Comment: I think this would be better researched/asked at [so] because it is about Python string manipulation rather than specific to GIS.

Comment: @PolyGeo You're right... but actually ArMoraer 's comment worked. Should I delete the question since it's not really applicable here? (Sorry, pretty new to stackexchange, not sure of etiquette)

Comment: Rather than deleting it I think it will be better just closed to let it act as a signpost to [so] for such questions.